# I would like to create an incremental number for each item that is shown

Tags: php, loops

In this site (given the link below), I show a series of articles. I would like for each of these articles to write a number below. For example: if there are 5 items, each of them will have 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 at the bottom

I tried to do in multiple ways, with jquery, with a javascript loop but in this case it gives me an error because the variable is rewritten for each article.

```
<?php  /** * Template name: 01. Pagina master */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="col-sm-12 works" id="content">
  <div class="row grid">
      <!-- MAIN-->
      <main id="main">
        <section id="fs-container"
             style="background-image:url(http://www.domuspoint.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/pergole_domus_point_-8.jpg);">

        <?php
          $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=> 'work', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => 0  ) );  
          while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
            $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
        ?>
          <div class="media-project-hover" data-background="<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>">
            <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
            <div class="media__body">
              <h5 class="media__sub-title title-sub">SOLE</h5>
              <h3 class="media__title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              </h3>
              <a class="link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">vedi</a>
            </div>
            <span class="media__number" id="bello">5</span>
          </div>
        <?php
          endwhile; wp_reset_query();
        ?>

        </section>
      </main>
      <!-- END MAIN-->
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

https://pastebin.com/KbdzNiZF

Comment: Just increment a counter variable inside the while loop then, and output the value of that in the place where you want it …?

Comment: outside/before your loop create a `<?php $counter = 1; ?>`
inside your while loop `<?php echo $counter;$counter++ ?>`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a counter, and incrementing it after each loop iteration?

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=> 'work', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => 0  ) );  
    counter = 1; //the counter
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
        $loop->the_post();  
        $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
    ?>
        <span class="media__number" id="bello"><?= $counter ?></span>
    <?php
        $counter += 1; //increment counter
    endwhile; wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: Now i try, i must type it after the actal loop? or in the loop?